# SwiftUI: Initialize @StateObject with binding

Tags: swift, swiftui, initialization

In my `init()`, I'm trying to initialize a `@StateObject` variable by passing in a binding to another variable in scope.

I want to achieve something like this:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State var value: Bool
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    init() {
        self.value = false
        self.viewModel = ViewModel($value)
    }
}
```

I know that when properties are needed during initialization normally, we can just create a copy of them and use the copy in the initializer. However, since I'm trying to use a binding, binding to a copy of a variable won't work.

How can I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Note, you should **not** have a `Binding` in a class, such as in your `class ViewModel: ObservableObject...`.
 `Binding` is only meaningful inside a `View`.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I didn't know that, thanks! what should we use instead then, assuming we want the same effect? or should this still never be done?

Comment: Correct, it should never be done. An ObservableObject class is where you use
 `@Published var value: Bool`. It really depends what you are trying to do. Re-structure your code
 so that you don't have a `binding` inside your class.
 Use the model directly in the `View`, for example, `$viewModel.value` where you had the view binding `value`.

Answer (score 2):

If `value` is bound to the view model anyway a better practice is to declare it in the view model as `@Published` property

```
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var value = false
}

struct MyView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Toggle("Switch something", isOn: $viewModel.value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this help?
With this, you can store the property value inside of the ViewModel and then you can use the value later with something like `$viewModel.value`.

```
struct MyView: View {    
    @StateObject private var viewModel: ViewModel
    init() {
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ViewModel(value: false))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

chuan322's answer is a good answer but you can revise it a little as below:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State var value: Bool
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    init(value: Bool) {
        self.value = value
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ViewModel(value: value))
    }
}
```